# How do I change my Workspace name in P4v?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a Workspace that I would like to rename in P4V.

So far, I have tried doing so by navigating to Connection -> Edit Current Workspace. However, the 'Workspace name' field is not editable.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented on [perforce documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html) client (workspace) name is field read-only, so it is not editable.

You can still copy that workspace and name it differently.
To do so open Workspaces tab (View > Workspaces) and search for your workspace on the list. Right-click on it and select "Create new workspace from 'XXX'..."

Answer (score 0):

As of Perforce Helix Core Server v2022.2, you can now rename a client workspace.

From P4V, in the Workspaces view, you can right click your Workspace and select the "Rename Workspace" option.

Or from the command line, you can do this with p4 CLI:

> p4 renameclient --from=joe --to=joe-martin

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_renameclient.html
https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/Renaming-a-client